# Align buttons up and down using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Im trying to make a panel  with buttons that have the next arrangement side by side in columns:

[image]

But I don't know how to this.

Here is my code

```css
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: vertical;
 
}

label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
 display: inline-block;
  
 
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
 display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
 

}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #23364B;
    padding: 20px;
 display:inline-block;


}

.col-25 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* this is for when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}


body {
    background-color:#23364B;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
 float: right;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>Some title</h2>


<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">key 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="some" name="somethig" placeholder="some text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname">key2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="some again" name="more something" placeholder="more text">
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="action 1">
    </div>
  <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="action 2">
    </div>
  <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="action 3">
    </div>
  <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="action 4">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="action 5">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="action 6">
    </div>
 
  </form>
</div>
<a href="1.html">1</a>
</body>
```

Im guessing that @media screen, the .col-25 and .col-75 statements on  css  are  messing in, but at the same time I dont see how, since this only acts (I think) in the space assignation inside the text areas,labels and buttons, but not outside this elements.

**UPDATE**
The statements mentioned  in the css has nothing to do.

Comment: why not just put your buttons in col divs within the rows - two per row? https://www.bootply.com/0fcHnEJcHO - or you don't even need the row seperators: https://www.bootply.com/C4etafDdPF

Comment: Both of these are right ! I didnt see it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `div` is a block level element, placing a element inside a `div` will normally move it to next line. In your case , you can use css grid system. and define how many columns you will like to have

```css
.button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some title</h2>
<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">key 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="some" name="somethig" placeholder="some text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname">key2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="some again" name="more something" placeholder="more text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-container">
      <input type="submit" value="action 1">


      <input type="submit" value="action 2">

      <input type="submit" value="action 3">


      <input type="submit" value="action 4">


      <input type="submit" value="action 5">


      <input type="submit" value="action 6">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
<a href="1.html">1</a>
```

Comment: Both of the answers in the comments and this fullfill what I have asked, I only selected this because it is a bit more flexible to adust.